# Compute sum of values for repeating keys in a List

Tags: json, transform, jolt

We have a requirement to find the sum of a particular key type from a list. The type may repeat in the list i.e it can have multiple values in the list.

Here, we want to get the sum of amount field values from the returnItemAdjustments list with returnAdjustmentTypeId = 'RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ'.

Sample Input:

```json
[
  {
    "returnId": "10051",
    "returnItemAdjustments": [
      {
        "returnItemSeqId": "00001",
        "amount": 28.64,
        "returnAdjustmentTypeId": "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ",
        "description": "Return Sales Tax",
        "createdDate": null,
        "returnId": "10051",
        "returnAdjustmentId": "10051",
        "comments": "Return Sales Tax",
        "shipGroupSeqId": null
      },
      {
        "returnItemSeqId": "00001",
        "amount": 58.64,
        "returnAdjustmentTypeId": "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ",
        "description": "Return Sales Tax",
        "createdDate": null,
        "returnId": "10051",
        "returnAdjustmentId": "10051",
        "comments": "Return Sales Tax",
        "shipGroupSeqId": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "returnId": "10051",
    "returnItemAdjustments": [
      {
        "returnItemSeqId": "00002",
        "amount": 38.64,
        "returnAdjustmentTypeId": "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ",
        "description": "Return Sales Tax",
        "createdDate": null,
        "returnId": "10051",
        "returnAdjustmentId": "10051",
        "comments": "Return Sales Tax",
        "shipGroupSeqId": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
  {
    "returnId": "10051",
    "returnTax": 87.28
  },
  {
    "returnId": "10051",
    "returnTax": 38.64
  }
]
```

Can some one help to identify the possible Jolt Spec for this problem statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the sum of amount fields from returnAdjustmentsList for each returnId, then this spec might help you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "returnItemAdjustments": {
          "*": {
            "returnAdjustmentTypeId": {
              "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ": {
                "@(2,amount)": "[&5].returnSalesTaxAmount[]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "@": "[&]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "returnSalesTaxTotalAmount": "=doubleSum(@(1,returnSalesTaxAmount))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "returnId": "[&1].returnId",
        "returnSalesTaxTotalAmount": "[&1].returnTax"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    // group by returnAdjustmentTypeId, returnItemSeqId, returnAdjustmentId attributes to reform new objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "returnItemAdjustments": {
          "*": {
            "amount": "@(1,returnAdjustmentTypeId).@(1,returnItemSeqId).@(1,returnAdjustmentId).&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // filter objects tagged "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ" only while grouping by "returnItemSeqId"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "RET_SALES_TAX_ADJ": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // sum up the amount values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=doubleSum(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[#3].returnId",
          "@": "[#3].returnTax"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```